# give different shapes to object in scatter plot

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have a basic question with ggplot
I have a dataframe with a column merged from another df. there are about 10000 rows:

```
mytab
              FC1         ID            FC2
1    0.3379713197        ff            0.3392757588
2   -0.8787452838        gg           -0.8746986951
3    0.5918856725        Gm            0.5994792851
4   -0.0180385364        xx           -0.0261098608
5    0.1258282187        ii            0.1358723158
```

basically I need to do a scatter plot which in X there is FC1, in Y FC2.
I do this:

```
mytab$up <- NA
mytab$up[mytab$FC1>=0] <- "red"
mytab$up[mytab$FC2>=0] <- "darkred"

mytab$down <- NA
    mytab$down[mytab$FC1<=0] <- "lightblue"
    mytab$down[mytab$FC2<=0] <- "blue"
```

Values are similar so if I colour them, they overlaps so I can't see the position of IDs on scatter plot.
my idea is to give a different shape to values to be able to distinguish them.
I don't know if it is the right way so I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Look here. https://environmentalcomputing.net/graphics/ggplot/ggplot-colour-shapes/

Comment: Thanks, I read this tutorial but Is not exactly what I need